# Use multiple components on one React Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to learning React and so far as I have been exploring its amazing. I have a quick question which is how can I display multiple modules such as "app.js" and "About.js" on one page? is this possible?

Here is some images that may help.

[React App.js and About.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dX9c.png)

[React index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRIL6.png)

[React js console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7bzq.png)

Comment: you could use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: I know this is probably a dumb question but how do I add this, I have seen it but havent obviously tried it myself

Comment: modules? do you mean components?

Comment: Here's what I would do. 
Whenever I'm trying something new. I go through the docs, copy-paste the examples, and see how it's working and then change that example to fit what I need.

Since in the future, I would be exposed to something new every day. I use this as my mental framework.

If even after trying, it fails. Then I would ask the question.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá I am actually looking through some now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Commonly in a react app, you will route based on different URLs.

The different 'modules' (also known as components) are typically defined in other JS files. See the HomePage and AboutPage files in the example below.

First, import the other pages.
Second, route to them given a path.

A common routing solution in React is [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './pages/HomePage.js';
import AboutPage from './pages/AboutPage.js';

const MyApp = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Sounds good - I wrote that from memory, so there's likely some syntax / potentially wrong names of react router's stuff used. But the point is think of your 'pages' as just another React component like a NavBar that you'll render in particular places.